# Issues with catalog shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm running in to a few hitches in a shell script I'm making for my job. Everything seems to be working correctly until it gets to the point where it kills the instance of chrome that is displaying a catalog and then opens an instance of chrome that displays a slideshow if the raspberry pi is idle long enough.

What I am seeing is the slideshow chrome getting killed even though nothing has been touched. I can't tell if it's xprintidle even though I'm running an echo script to check what the idle timer displays, when chrome gets killed sometimes the idle timer has been reset indicating activity and sometimes it's not reset and still in the timeframe where it should be displaying that slideshow.

This is the code that runs the first part, it runs in a loop and checks to make sure chrome is open to the catalog page unless the screensaver.status file is present this makes sure that if the catalog gets closed by a user it will reopen (This script is ran at boot as an autorun):

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do

RUNNING=$(pidof chromium-browse)

if [ -n "$RUNNING" ] && [ ! -f /home/pi/statusfiles/screensaver.status ]
    then
        sleep 1
    else
        touch /home/pi/statusfiles/catalog.status
        chromium-browser --start-maximized --user-data-dir=/home/pi/chromiumsessions/chromiumlive --incognito http://www.google.com
        sleep 10
fi
sleep 1
done
```

This is the code that runs the process to kill the screensaver process when the mouse is moved (causing xprintidle to reset) this also clears the user data out of the chrome instance every 2 minutes, and when xprintidle reaches a certain time it kills the catalog chrome session and opens up the screensaver session (This script is run as a cronjob):

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
RUNNING=$(pidof chromium-browse)
IDLETIME=$(export DISPLAY=:0 && sudo -u pi xprintidle)

if [ "$IDLETIME" -lt "120000" ] && [ ! -f /home/pi/statusfiles/catalog.status ]
    then
        killall chromium-browser
        rm -rf /home/pi/statusfiles/screensaver.status
    else
        sleep 1
fi

if [ "$IDLETIME" -gt "120000" ] && [ "$IDLETIME" -lt "300000" ] && [ -f /home/pi/statusfiles/catalog.status ]
    then
        killall chromium-browser
        sleep 1
        rm -rf /home/pi/chromiumsessions/chromiumlive
        rm -rf /home/pi/Downloads/*
        mkdir /home/pi/chromiumsessions/chromiumlive
        chown -R pi:pi /home/pi/chromiumsessions/chromiumlive
        cp -R /home/pi/chromiumsessions/chromiumgood/* /home/pi/chromiumsessions/chromiumlive/
        chown -R pi:pi /home/pi/chromiumsessions/chromiumlive
        rm -rf /home/pi/statusfiles/catalog.status
        sleep 120
    else
        sleep 1
fi

if [ "$IDLETIME" -gt "300000" ] && [ ! -f /home/pi/statusfiles/screensaver.status ]
    then
        touch /home/pi/statusfiles/screensaver.status
        killall chromium-browser
        rm -rf /home/pi/statusfiles/catalog.status
        chromium-browser --temp-profile --kiosk --start-fullscreen http://www.google.com/
    else
        sleep 1
fi

done
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably should add logging to your kill blocks so that you can see which condition was matched: `echo "$(date --rfc-3339=seconds) cond-1" >>/path/to/kill.log`